# Show that $f(z)$ analytic and $c_1f(z)+c_2\overline{f(z)}=0$ implies $f(z)$ constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Be $f(z)$ analytic in $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ not simultaneously zero, if $c_1f(z)+c_2\overline{f(z)}=0$ in $D$ show that $f(z)$ is constant in $D$.

I am stuck with this problem, I appreciate some hint, I think liuville's theorem is the right one to see that $f'(z)=0$, but I don't see how to apply it in an easy way.

Comment: Use `\overline` instead of `\bar` for longer expressions as it will adapt to the length.

Comment: Is $D$ an arbitrary domain? Also, shouldn't $c_1$ and $c_2$ be not simultaneously zero?

Comment: yes, I had forgotten that they are not simultaneously zero and yes, D is arbitrary.

Comment: Which definition of holomorphic do you have? CR or the z-bar derivative?

Comment: Liouville's theorem does not apply to $f$ since $f$ is not even defined on all of $\mathbb{C}$. But you could e.g. assume $c_2 \neq 0$ and take the partial derivative with respect to $\bar{z}$ to get $f'(z) = 0$. Or, if you know the open mapping theorem, observe that $f$ maps $D$ into a line, and a line contains no open disk.

Comment: Why not use the Cauchy–Riemann equations to show that $-c_2\overline{f(z)}$ is not analytic on $D$, while $c_1f(z)$ is?

Comment: Always the CR definition

Comment: @BenitoRonaldo "*yes, D is arbitrary*" $\;-\;$ It can't be completely arbitrary. If you assume that $D$ is a connected open set then you should state that in the question.

Comment: If either $c_1=0$ or $c_2=0$ then the result is immediate.  Otherwise you can write $ \frac{-c_1}{c_2} f(z)\cdot f(z) = \big \vert f(z)\big\vert^2 \in \mathbb R$ which prove that the analytic function on the LHS is constant so $f(z)\cdot f(z)$ is constant and $f(z)$ takes on at most 2 values; for reasons of connectivity $f(z)$ is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, suppose $c_2 \neq 0$. Since $f$ is analytic and $\overline{f} = -(c_1/c_2) f$, then $\overline{f}$ is analytic. Use the CR-equations for $f = u + iv$ and $\overline{f} = u - iv$ to show that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(z) = R(z) e^{jA(z)}$$.

$$f(z) = \frac{-c_2}{c_1} \bar{f(z)}$$
$$\implies R(z) e^{jA(z)}= \frac{-c_2}{c_1} R(z) e^{-jA(z)}$$
$$\implies R(z) = |c_2|/|c_1| R(z) \implies |c_2| = |c_1|$$
$$\implies 2A(z) = \angle{\frac{-c_2}{c_1}} + 2n(z)\pi$$
$$\implies A(z) = 0.5\angle{\frac{-c_2}{c_1}} + n(z)\pi$$

Hence $$f(z) = R(z) e^{j (\theta +n(z) \pi)}$$
where $\theta = 0.5\angle{\frac{-c_2}{c_1}}$ is a fixed constant.
$n(z)$ is an integer depending on $z$.

Hence we have $$f(z) = R(x,y) cos(\theta +n(x,y) \pi) + i R(x,y) sin(\theta +n(x,y) \pi)$$

Apply Cauchy Riemann equation:

$$\frac{\partial R(x,y) cos(\theta +n(x,y) \pi)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial R(x,y) sin(\theta +n(x,y) \pi)}{\partial y}$$

$$\frac{\partial R(x,y) cos(\theta +n(x,y) \pi)}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial R(x,y) sin(\theta +n(x,y) \pi)}{\partial x}$$

If in a neighbourhood of $(x,y)$, $n(x,y) = constant = n \implies$

$$cos(\theta +n \pi) \frac{\partial R(x,y) }{\partial x} = sin(\theta +n \pi) \frac{\partial R(x,y) }{\partial y}$$

$$cos(\theta +n \pi) \frac{\partial R(x,y) }{\partial y} = -sin(\theta +n \pi) \frac{\partial R(x,y) }{\partial x}$$

Both above equations can be true only iff $$\frac{\partial R(x,y) }{\partial y} = \frac{\partial R(x,y) }{\partial x} = 0$$

$n(x,y)$ is constant almost everywhere.

So for all but countably many points:
$$\frac{\partial R(x,y) }{\partial y} = \frac{\partial R(x,y) }{\partial x} = 0$$

for almost everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$:
Hence $R(x,y) = constant = R(z)$

for almost everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$:
Hence we have $f(z) = constant \times e^{j \theta + n(x,y)\pi}$

By continuity of $f$,
$$n(x,y) = constant $$

Hence we have $f(z) = constant \times e^{j( \theta + n \pi)}$